# What's the meaning of "Required" in "- dynamicAnimatorDidPause: Required"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I wanted to use the `<UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate>` protocol, and found reference in Apple's `UIKit Framework Reference`, where it says

```
- dynamicAnimatorDidPause:Required
```

However, in `UIDynamicAnimator.h`, the declaration of this method is `optional`:

```
@protocol UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)dynamicAnimatorWillResume:(UIDynamicAnimator*)animator;
- (void)dynamicAnimatorDidPause:(UIDynamicAnimator*)animator;
@end
```

So what's the meaning of "`Required`" in the reference documentation?

Comment: Can you share a link to this reference? I'm not seeing it in [`UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate` Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate). Not sure where you're seeing this. But the [iOS 8.0 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/UIKit.html) would seem to suggest that it used to be required but is now optional.

Comment: `- dynamicAnimatorDidPause:Required` is just in your link... I'm not sure about the meaning of "Required" since the method is optional. Thank you for the second link, that may explain the reason. ^_^

Comment: Ah, I see what you're talking about. Looking at that document revision history, it was created 2013-09-18, but it doesn't appear to have been updated for the changes noted in the iOS 8.0 API diffs document, which suggests that effective iOS 8, this is now optional. The protocol reference would appear to be out of date.